Unable to create cloud private nat on gcp using google_compute_router_nat
Description: "type" parameter is not working in the resource google_compute_router_nat
I’m attempting to create a private Cloud NAT resource on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using Terraform. My configuration involves the google_compute_router_nat resource, which is intended to set up a NAT gateway that restricts outbound IP access to internal IP ranges.I’ve been referring to the documentation provided by Terraform and Google, specifically the example usage for router NAT private. Following this, I’ve tried to configure the type parameter to "PRIVATE", expecting it to restrict the NAT to private (internal) IP addresses only.
However, when I run terraform apply, I get the following error message:
Error: Unsupported argument
│
│ on .terraform/modules/cloud-nat-test/cloud_nat.tf line 20, in resource "google_compute_router_nat" "cloud_nat":
│ 20: type = "PRIVATE"
│
│ An argument named "type" is not expected here.
It seems that Terraform does not recognize the type argument within the google_compute_router_nat resource. I have verified that I am using the correct provider version (6.4.0 for Google) but have not found a solution that allows me to set this resource as private.Here’s the configuration I’m working with:
**Reference : **https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_router_nat#example-usage---router-nat-private
Terraform Configuration
resource "google_compute_router_nat" "cloud_nat" {
  project                             = var.project_id
  name                                = var.cloud_nat_name
  router                              = google_compute_router.router.name
  region                              = google_compute_router.router.region
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat  = var.source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat
  enable_endpoint_independent_mapping = var.enable_endpoint_independent_mapping
  min_ports_per_vm                    = var.min_ports_per_vm
  nat_ip_allocate_option              = var.nat_ip_allocate_option
  type                                = "PRIVATE"
  subnetwork {
    name                    = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.id
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["ALL_IP_RANGES"]
  }
  rules {
    rule_number = var.rule_number
    description = "rule for private nat"
    match       = var.match
    action {
      source_nat_active_ranges = [
        data.google_compute_subnetwork.vpc_subnetwork.id
      ]
    }
  }
}

**Terraform Version**

terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
       source  = "hashicorp/google"
       version = "6.4.0"
    }
  }
}

Expected behavior: I would like the configuration to create a private Cloud NAT resource in GCP using Terraform.
Observed behavior: I receive an error message stating that the type argument is not expected here.
Research and Attempts:

I reviewed the official Terraform documentation for google_compute_router_nat, and I understand the argument for type may not exist in the current version of the provider.

I’ve also tried removing type and adjusting the source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat and nat_ip_allocate_option parameters to control the scope of the NAT, but it doesn’t give the explicit “private” configuration I am looking for.


Question: How can I achieve a private NAT configuration without the type argument in google_compute_router_nat? Are there alternative parameters or settings I should use to replicate a private NAT setup?

As it is documented in [1] you must use the beta provider google-beta [2] in order to use the type parameter, so please install and update your provider and give it a try.


type - (Optional, Beta) Indicates whether this NAT is used for public or private IP translation. If unspecified, it defaults to PUBLIC. If PUBLIC NAT used for public IP translation. If PRIVATE NAT used for private IP translation. Default value is PUBLIC. Possible values are: PUBLIC, PRIVATE.


[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_router_nat#type
[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions#google-beta
